# Retrieve the different in hours between 2 dates

Tags: php, sql, datetime, clock

I would appreciate it if someone could help me with some logic here on how to turn my timestamp function into a working payroll service.

Right now when a user logs in to my site, they can click a clock in button which timestamps the `datetime` format into SQL.

This is the format: `2013-05-12 09:19:00`

- On click, it starts the clock in the `in` column.
- When they click again, it adds to the `out` column.

It is storing in these columns:

- id (auto_increment)
- userid (unique)
- in (datetime)
- out (datetime)

How would a function look / work to grab total hours clocked from an employee?

At the least, point me in the right direction to resolve this scenario please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take advantage of the MySQL functions [**`SUM`**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) and [**`TIMESTAMPDIFF`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) to calculate it for you:

```
SELECT SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, `in`, `out`)) AS hours
  FROM myTable
 WHERE userid = 1
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/605e06/1/0)

Comment: ok so MySql will know to grab the HOUR from datetime like that? and the in, out is referring to my columns?

Comment: yes `in` and `out`are your columns it will be a 1 row result given you specify the `userid` so you can grab it as you would normally do `$row['hours']`

Comment: ok but in order to get the total hours between two dates. I am going to have to separate the date from the datetime right?

Comment: @NichoDiaz no, this will calculate the difference between the 2 `DATETIME` values given and return the hours, and the `SUM` function will sum all the hours calculated into a gran total, so if user is in today at 1pm and leaves today at 3pm that is 2 hours. You can test it on your MySQL table directly and see the result yourself. **At the top of my answer there is a link to `SUM` and another to `TIMESTAMPDIFF` that you can click and see the documentation which also have examples.**

Comment: ok awesome thanks man. I think this going to help a ton but i get in error when I run in SQL. do you see what it could be from?

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'in, out)) AS hours FROM clock WHERE userid = 40' at line 1

Comment: @NichoDiaz what is the exact name of your columns? I believe `in` and `out` are reserved names on MySQL so you will have to use backticks around those. like `\`in\``. Here is a working sample of the above: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/605e06/1/0

Comment: `in` and `out` are in fact reserved words http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html and must be wrapped in backticks or use a different name for the columns.

Comment: @NichoDiaz oh and just to illustrate on the live demo, `userid` 1 works 8 hours a day for 5 days which results on 40 hours which I hope answer your question about the date format ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would select all rows with the user id, and in PHP would get function like this:

```
$time = 0;
while($row = $query->fetch_object())
{
    $time += (strtotime($row->out) - strtotime($row->in));
}
```

And then `$time` would be the total time which you can format in your favourite way.

Comment: Ok but your saying take the total out and subtract the total in from it.. right? If so how will this work with the format being 2013-05-12 09:19:00

Answer (score 0):

I would use a mysql query :

```
select SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(session_duration))) as total_session_duration
    from (
        select timediff(`in`, `out`) as session_duration 
            from employees_log #your table_name here
            where userid = [your user id]
) as t_duration
```

Couldn't test it, but I'm pretty sure this should work.